# A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "No extended information available." calling geography

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlgeography

I'm trying to pull lat/lon coordinates from one table and see if they intersect a particular area using geometry::STIntersect. However, I get the error in the title after the query has started running and producing results. This only happens intermittently, though. Below is a pseudocode example of what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_with_lat_lons
INNER JOIN(SELECT id,1 include 
    FROM table_with_lat_lons 
    INNER JOIN table_with_geog_boundaries 
    ON table_with_geog_boundaries.geog.STIntersects(geography::Point(ISNULL(CAST(y_Coord as float),0.0), ISNULL(Cast(x_Coord as float),0.0), 4326)) = 1) bounds 
    ON table_with_lat_lons.id =bounds.id
    WHERE bounds.include=1
```

Wrapping everything into a with...then will fix the error, but that's not a viable solution for this issue for me

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/2791) help? It looks like it might be a version specific bug that can be worked around by adding the [`MaxDoP 1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-ver15) hint.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much!